# Is here okay to post a question about computer science lore?

Tags: discussion

Is this an appropriate site to ask about computer science lore? I'd originally [asked at the Computer Science Stack Exchange Meta](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1770/is-here-okay-to-post-a-question-about-computer-science-lore) whether there was okay to ask about a half-remembered story about two computer scientists solving a word-counting problem - one with C and the other with Unix shell. A commenter at that question pointed me to [a writeup on the story](https://leancrew.com/all-this/2011/12/more-shell-less-egg/), which was actually Knuth's Pascal implementation versus McIlroy's Unix shell implementation, and further pointed me here as a potentially appropriate site for the question.

So I'll pose the question here: is History of Science and Mathematics an appropriate site for questions about identifying computer science lore from partly-remembered details?

(Perhaps noteworthy: a sizeable portions of questions at Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange of this nature -- identifying a specific work from partly-remembered details)

Comment: Can you clarify what you understand perspectively under "computer *science"*? As there is also https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/ this might be crucial — or overlapping — for he kind(s) of Qs you want to ask.

Comment: @LаngLаngС - hmm...I think my perspective definition of "computer science" is well represented by this quote from Wikipedia: "Computer science deals with the theoretical foundations of information, algorithms and the architectures of its computation as well as practical techniques for their application." And this question, specifically, is about a famous(?) story about different philosophies of organizing/implementing thereof.